# Azure DevOps: Can not see all items in backlog

Tags: azure-devops, backlog

we use Scrum as the process in our Azure DevOps project.

when i am in the Backlog and have selected Epics I can see all my Items but when I switch to Features or Backlog items I can not see them all.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzuRH.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHCDe.png)

I am confused, is it a bug or am I doing something wrong

Thanks for your help
Christian

Comment: Are you filtering by a keyword or something? Press the filter button at the top right corner. Check for the filter you're using

Comment: In our case we were using a weird hierarchy (feature -> user story -> epic -> work item / bug, please don't challenge it) so that only work items respecting the official hierarchy would be displayed (even partially, i.e. epic -> work item would show). Reverting all work items to the official hierarchy allows us to use backlogs and taskboards entirely. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72877849/1945549 brought me to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some feature items are not displayed when you switch to `Features`, this is because these items are owned by other teams.

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/backlogs-overview?view=azure-devops#work-with-multi-team-ownership-of-backlog-items) ,we can know that :

> Items that are owned by other teams appear with an information icon,[image].

If you want to display these items, you need to switch to the corresponding team.

Below is my reproduction:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you, that was a hint in the right direction.

i actually had only one Team but the items were owned by another Team because the Area Path was owned by the Team