# Azure DevOps: work items do not appear in the backlog

Tags: azure-devops

I just created a list of work items, under a project in Azure DevOps: 1 epic and 3 features (these 3 are child linked to the epic).

[image]

But when I go to the backlogs to see these items, they are not shown. I get the following message:

[image]

I tried a couple of solutions that I found on the web, but they do not work.

Please help me to figure out why these are not being shown in the backlog... (of course I'm new at Azure DevOps).

Thanks!

Comment: Create work items under the  backlog item. Epic -----> features---> backlog --->work item

Answer (score 2):

Create Tasks under the User Story.
`Epic ---> Features---> User Story --->Tasks`. So then in the backlog top right corner when you select Epic,  `Features, User Story, Tasks` will appear. When you select the Feature,  `User Story, Tasks` will appear. When you select the  User Story, `Tasks` will appear.

[image: Azure board]

[image: select parent level]

[Reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/define-features-epics?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process)

Comment: We were using a weird hierarchy (feature -> user story -> epic -> work item / bug, please don't challenge it) so that only work items respecting the official hierarchy would be displayed (even partially, i.e. epic -> work item would show). We'll revert to the official hierarchy to be able to use backlogs and taskboards entirely. This answer brought me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, I can see that only epic and feature:

[image]

You need to select epic or feature type in this place:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by going through the different buttons on the screen:

1. Go to Configure Team Settings (when selected a box will be displayed)

[image]

2. Be sure that in the Backlog section all items are selected (in my case they weren´t)

[image]

3. Be sure that all of the work items in different levels are shown by clicking on the + symbol. (the - symbol will hide them).

[image]

And that is it!